# Listbox item in foreach Condition

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I like to get the string of the current item in foreach condition.

```
 public void checkStock()
 {
    foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(GetStock(listBox1.Items.ToString())) == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item not in stock  ");
        }
    }
 }
```

So that I can display the name of the item that is not in stock like "

```
MessageBox.Show("{0}" +"not in stock" , listbox.items.ToString());
```

Comment: Which problem are you facing?

Comment: do you mean: MessageBox.Show("{0}" +"not in stock" , listBoxItem.ToString());

Comment: yes sorry for confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public void checkStock()
    {
        foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
        {
            // use the currently iterated list box item
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} is not in stock!",listBoxItem.ToString()));

        }
    }
```

I dont know how you are supposed to check if it really IS in stock though - this basically just iterates the collection, and prints out each item. You didn't specify how to check the stock.

Comment: there is no value property after listBoxItem

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. You were trying to convert all the items to a string representation. :)

Answer (score 0):

This'l work as well:

```
MessageBox.Show("{0} not in stock", listBoxItem.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [string.format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method with the foreach local variable `listBoxItem` which i guess should be used to check wether the item is in the stok too.

```
public void checkStock()
 {
    foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(GetStock(listBoxItem.ToString())) == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} is not in stock!",listBoxItem.ToString()));
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: there is no .value property after listBoxItem

Answer (score 0):

You can use listBoxItem local variable inside if clause.