# How to generate automatic codes that import text in a Text box in Window Form for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, vscode-extensions

I am just new to Microsoft Window Form C#. I have one problem that I really need your help.

Below is a Text Box that I have written my G-code commands inside (in the Form1.design) after clicking on START. I would like to create automatic generated codes in the **Form1.cs** in a specific place by repeating the command translator.Translate(**""**) and put the according line of G-code in a text box inside the **""**.

[image]

For example: as you can see here, I have inserted G28 as a first line in a textbox, then I just wanna put that code into the " " space and generate the code translator.Translate("G28"). So do the process with other lines.
[image]
I have tried to read many but nothing has worked so far. Would anyone help me with this issue please?

Comment: Do you mean you want to iterate through the items in the textbox and run `translator.Translate(X)` on them, with `X` beng the string from the textbox line? If so, you can take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators

Comment: Yes, please use "string line in textBox1.Lines" to traverse the text box. Please refer to Kaygee Del Hlobo's answer, which should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but that looks like a listbox. Unless I am wrong however for a listbox, you iterate through the items like this.

```
foreach (string s in listBox1.Items)
{
    // s will be the item
}
```

Credit: [Listbox item in foreach Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156215/listbox-item-in-foreach-condition)

If indeed it is a textbox, then it will most likely be a multiline textbox and its items can be accessed with something like:

```
foreach(string line in textBox1.Lines)
{
    //your code, but working with 'line' - one at a time

}
```

Credit: [Read Each Line of 2 Multiline Text Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155831/read-each-line-of-2-multiline-text-box)

With that being said, in order to use your example, you could do something like:

```
foreach(string line in textBox1.Lines)
    {
        //your code, but working with 'line' - one at a time
        translator.Translate(line);
    }
```

The above code assumes that the name of your textbox is textbox1.